# Concurrent Users in MS Access (2007)

Tags: ms-access, concurrency

I am supposed to make our MS Access application work in parallel. Basically we will always at most be 3 people that need concurrent access (so from what I read this should not be too much of a problem traffic-wise).

Mostly we will all need to work on the same table (well, it's actually 3 tables, but with this access tool you can always open the sub-tables directly by clicking on the +).

I am having a hard time finding information on how to do this, so any pointers to good articles would be welcome.

Also I would like to be able to see who changed what... So implement some sort of logging.

At the moment the database lies somewhere, we download it (write that it is in use), make changes and upload it back. It's a stone-age solution and I need to change this asap.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to make DDL changes (e.g. changes to table structure) concurrently, or do you just mean 3 users will be adding and removing data concurrently?

Comment: only updates, inserts and deletes need to be performed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to stick the mdb/accdb file on a network drive, and make people open it from there, rather than copying it locally first. 3 concurrent users probably won't crash it too often, but make sure you take regular backups.

As for logging, well, it's easy enough to audit changes made via forms, but not so much with tables. Have a look at this thread http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/creating-audit-trail-of-all-edits-to-database-22382.html

Comment: ehm I'm not quite sure I understand. So if 3 people open the file from the same location (not locally) and do changes in the same table then this should not cause any problems? The locking of the entries will happen automatically?

Comment: Yeah that's the whole point of MS Access. Try it on a dummy copy first if you don't believe me.

Comment: ah hehe, nono, I do believe you :) I am just amazed :) So that is pretty great! Thanks a lot for your help and also the link to the logging, that looks very helpful.